# how to change the theme for datebox in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, themeroller, datebox

For `datevox` in `JqueryMobile` I want to change `pickPageOAHighButtonTheme` and `pickPageTodayButtonTheme`

how may I change them in by using a custom theme from [themeroller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) , what I need to set in `themeroller`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set anything specific in themeroller - those two options (and the other options like it) take a theme swatch letter - i.e., the same as writing data-theme="c".

If your question is to what *parts* of the theme those use, I'd have to dig, but I'd suspect it is most probably using the button theme, and if not, probably the toolbar theme.

Hope this helps.

~j